# App freezes when I try to get all data from database

Tags: android, sqlite

I was trying to implement a database in my app and one of the methods in my Database Handler is:

```
    public List<Product> GetAllProducts(){
    List<Product> prodList = new ArrayList<Product>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS, null); // TABLE_PRODUCTS is the name of the Table(String)

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Product product = new Product(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(3))); // The parameters are: Id(int), Name(String), Supermarket(String), Price(float)
            prodList.add(product);
        } while(cursor.moveToFirst());
    }

    db.close();
    cursor.close();

    return prodList;
}
```

This code is supposed to return a List of Products with all products in the database, but everytime this method is called the app freezes and I get the following output from the Android Studio console multiple times:

```
05-15 14:50:38.886    4774-4790/name.com.nameI/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 216342(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 17% free, 22MB/26MB, paused 18.456ms total 226.283ms
```

After freezing the app crashes.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can perform database tasks inside Asynctask .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your while loop from:

```
while(cursor.moveToFirst());
```

to:

```
while(cursor.moveToNext());
```

Answer (score 0):

Gathering the data from your source take a while and this process is running on your UI Thread(the main thread) so try to process the data on a new thread and then parse the data to the UI one . You can refer to AsyncTask and FutureTask.